# ¿Conoce la causa de este error?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

Buenas noches, mi duda es la siguiente, tengo un sitio web creado en asp.net que esta trabajando con una BD de SQLServer pero al momento de ejecutar mi código esta resultando este error y he tratado de buscar una solución pero no encuentro que me esta causando esto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomendaría que pongas RL código que estas haciendo uso para poder ayudarte

Comment: El servidor SQL esta corriendo??

Comment: Sería interesante ver el ConnectionString para poder ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0):

El error india que no hay conección con el servidor, puedes verificar que tengas al puerto del sql(por defecto al 1433) desde la consola mediante un `telnet servidorSql 1433` en caso de que no este instalado el telnet lo puedes probar por powershell

```
`Test-NetConnection -Port 1433 -ComputerName servidorSql`
```

O mendiante

```
(new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Connect("10.45.23.109", 443)`
```

Verifica los protocolos tcp debe estar habilitado.